# Unpivot with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have tables:

**Prices** (sellerId, usdBidPrice, usdAskPrice, eurBidPrice, eurAskPrice, gbpBidPrice, gbpAskPrice) with values

```
(1, 1, 1.1, 1.14, 1.16, 0.8, 0.9)
```

**Currency** (ccyId, ccyDescription) with values

```
(1, 'USD'),
(2, 'EUR'),
(3, 'GBP')
```

Desired output:

```
sellerId    AvgPrice    Ccy
1           1.05        1
1           1.15        2
1           0.85        3
```

I have this working sample but don't like hardcoded values, is there any choice without it?

```
DECLARE @usdId INT;
DECLARE @eurId INT;
DECLARE @gbpId INT;

SELECT @usdId = ccyId 
FROM Currency (NOLOCK)
WHERE [description] = 'USD'

SELECT @eurId = ccyId 
FROM Currency (NOLOCK)
WHERE [description] = 'EUR'

SELECT @gbpId = ccyId 
FROM Currency (NOLOCK)
WHERE [description] = 'GBP'

SELECT
      sellerId,
      avgPrice,
      CASE currencyType 
        WHEN 'USD' THEN @usdId
        WHEN 'EUR' THEN @eurId
        WHEN 'GBP' THEN @gbpId
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Ccy
FROM
( 
      SELECT
            sellerId,
            (usdBidPrice + usdAskPrice) / 2 AS USD,
            (eurBidPrice + eurAskPrice) / 2 AS EUR,
            (gbpBidPrice + gbpAskPrice) / 2 AS GBP
      FROM Prices (NOLOCK)
) pricesRawData
unpivot
(
    avgPrice for currencyType in (USD, EUR, GBP)
)marks
```

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic SQL and UNPIVOT:

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols =STUFF((
SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(ccyDescription+'BidPrice')+','+QUOTENAME(ccyDescription+'AskPrice')
FROM #Currency
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  sellerId,
        AVG([Values]) as AvgPrice,
        ccyId
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #Prices) p
UNPIVOT (
    [Values] FOR Price in ('+@cols+')
) unpvt
INNER JOIN #Currency c
    ON c.ccyDescription = LEFT(Price,3)
GROUP BY sellerId, ccyId
'

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Result of printing:

```
SELECT  sellerId,
        AVG([Values]) as AvgPrice,
        ccyId
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #Prices) p
UNPIVOT (
    [Values] FOR Price in ([USDBidPrice],[USDAskPrice],[EURBidPrice],[EURAskPrice],[GBPBidPrice],[GBPAskPrice])
) unpvt
INNER JOIN #Currency c
    ON c.ccyDescription = LEFT(Price,3)
GROUP BY sellerId, ccyId
```

After executing you will get this output:

```
sellerId    AvgPrice    ccyId
1           1,05        1
1           1,15        2
1           0,85        3
```

Comment: thx but in future columns names may not match currency description

Comment: That is completely another question. This answer is on your **current** question. If columns will not match currency description - then it will be **another** query. If there are ANOTHER columns, please, add details to your question, or ask another one. Given sample gives solution to your current problem.